# Eclipse error in JSP file: The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the java build path

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee

I've done a research for a while and I haven't found any answer to an issue on my JSP file... I mean, it works but eclipse points out an error on the first line saying that

> The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the java build path

this is what the file looks like

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Runtime server is set on apache 10.0, the build path has the apache lib linked... And my servlet class is working fine with jakarta imports... The whole think works, the problem is just that Eclipse shows that error on the first line, when it should since the import now is done from jakarta, and I don't know if somehow this error that at this point does not affect the code, can affect on a bad way later on.

Thanks.

```
  [1]: https://prnt.sc/10lo0al
  [2]: http://prntscr.com/10lo2b2
  [3]: http://prntscr.com/10lo337
  [4]: http://prntscr.com/10lo3kh
  [Apache lib folder][1]
  [jsp file error][2]
  [targeted runtime checked][3]
  [apache lib][4]
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be resolved with an update to the 2021-03 release on Wednesday, using https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03 .

Comment: Did you rerun Validation?

Comment: A real genius would have figured out how to do that for everyone automatically, but it's nice to see that the updates are appreciated.

Comment: Well.. still have the error, yesterday it worked, today the error reappeared and I have done all the updates... I also edited and joined screenshots.

Comment: There's something odd in http://prntscr.com/10lo2b2 ; the "Java Resources" content provider was removed from 2021-03. Is this the same project as before? In any case, the About dialog's Installation Details should show an org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core plug-in version of 1.4.0.v202103040444 in the final 2021-03 release.